# Just built an Android app, need to develop it server-side. Where do I start with this? What language/software?

Tags: java, android, web-services

Basically, the server needs to host a database. Users can add a new posting via the phone app, which contains two text fields, email, a numeric identifier, and a picture. The postings are then sync'd back to the listing page of the phone app.

I was going to go with a private virtual server with MySql, but I don't know where to start with the design of this. Do I use Python or PHP? Do I use SOAP? What would you use to build this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you really want to manage your own database and server-side code, you may be better off using a service like [Parse](https://parse.com/products/data) that runs the database for you and lets you store objects via simple API calls from your Android code. I have not used Parse in particular so you may want to get other opinions about them.

If you are intent on rolling your own server, a VPS is a reasonable way to do it. There is no "best" language to use here, so if you have no experience with any, I would choose whatever language you *want* to learn. There is no better way to learn a language than through necessity.

Comment: Parse looks awesome. I was also considering Azure. Thanks!